Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password="root"  --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=opensearch --opensearch-host=os-host.example.com --opensearch-port=9200 --opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 --opensearch-timeout=15

This is my command. When I run this, I am facing an error. "Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster"
Now I want to fix this issue. Where is my mistake?

Magento 2.4+ requires Elasticsearch/OpenSearch
, Pls Make sure you Installed or have elasticsearch to supporting magento2
This is solution for me.

Install Docker

pull docker image elasticsearch with:



docker pull elasticsearch:7.17.19



run elasticsearch with:


docker run -d --name elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.17.19



check your elasticsearch is running on localhost:9200

Update your magento install command like this:



php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password="root"  --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --opensearch-host=localhost --opensearch-port=9200 --opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 --opensearch-timeout=15


Hopefully all of this will help you solve the issue with your Magento installation.
